# What is the best way to accurately describe this statistical probability?

Tags: probability

I am in the process of writing some information for an App. I need to express the probability of something happening but in a way that is correct but easy to understand. I'm confused on the actual math for this. I'll simplify the numbers here.

Assume a system has 1,000 possible unique codes and I have used 10. I set a computer to search for the codes at a rate of one per hour. How many hours statistically before I find a code ?

On the face of it, I am assuming 100 hours. But I have a feeling that this wouldn't be correct ?

Comment: Sorry, but, this is about pure probability question should be asked at math.se

Comment: "Assume a system has 1,000 possible unique codes and I have used 10"; were those 10 selected randomly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not on-topic in our site and it is about pure probability. Should be asked Math.SE.

Comment: It can be restated as randomly searching for $k$ cryptographic keys out of $n$ so its not off topic, I believe.

Comment: The question came from a background of finding a cryptographic key out of n possibilities which is why I ended up here but point taken, this is really a math issue at it's core.

Comment: As an additional note, I have two different answers here.. 50.5 and 100.. !

Answer (score 2):

So, the full analysis for random trials is that the initial probability of a hit is $p_0=k/n$ and $k=10,$ and $n=1000$ for your case. Define the number of trials until the first hit as $N_0$ which is a geometric random variable with expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}(N_0)=p_0^{-1}=\frac{n}{k}.
$$
This is indeed 100 as you guessed.

If you wanted  to find 2 codes your success probability would now be $$
p_1=(k-1)/n$$
and the expected time to find a second (distinct) code would be
$$
\mathbb{E}(N_0)=p_1^{-1}=\frac{n}{k-1},
$$
which is a little longer.

The expected time to find $r$ codes is thus
$$
\mathbb{E}(N_0)+ \mathbb{E}(N_1)+\cdots+ \mathbb{E}(N_{r-1})=
n\left(\frac{1}{k}+ \frac{1}{k-1}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{k-r+1}\right)
$$
which is $n(H_k-H_{k-r})$ where $H_k$ is the k_th harmonic number  (the sum of reciprocals of the first $k$ integers) and is approximately $\ln k$ for large $k$. So the overall time complexity is approximately
$$
n \ln \left(\frac{k}{k-r}\right)
$$
for $r>1.$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the computer tries a valid code **every time**. And that you picked which ones to use **randomly**. So the probability of a 'hit' :-

$$P_{\text{hit}} = \frac{10}{1,000} = 0.01$$

So at a rate of one attempt per hour, it will take an approximate **mean** time of $50 \frac{1}{2}$ hours to find the first code you used. That's an average of hitting the used code on the first attempt (after one hour), or on the last (after 100 hours). It's a simplification as we can only talk about an approximate mean (without calculating a time distribution $d(1, 990)$) as $P_{\text{hit}} = 1.0$ only after 990 attempts/hours.

It will take a slightly decreasing amount of time to find the next code and so on as the search space decreases. It's not much, but if you're interested, it's one for the maths people. As is $d$.

Comment: if you had 100 codes in total and were checking one by one then 50.5 average and 100 worst case trials would be correct. for this problem the probability of success in each trial is still 0.01 but 51 trials nowhere near exhaust the search space since you have to check each code individually